# Magento - Integrating Geo locationing with Multi - Website setup - bypass redirecting

Tags: php, magento

I am implementing a magento store that has a two website setup from the same installation. One is for Indian audience and the others is for international audience. Now, when a user types my domain say abcd.com, at first a geo-locationing script that returns whether or not the user is in India (based on his IP). The user will be redirected to the suitable website based on his IP geolocation afterwards. Besides, he may switch between stores/websites use the top menu if needed. My requirements are that both the websites should be on the same ".com"  domain as well as have the same "base_url".

Presently, I have configured the indian store at abcd.com/india and the other international one at abcd.com . Have created another set of .htaccess and index.php in a folder - /magento-root/india. In my original index.php in the magento root directorsy I call on some geo - locationing api calls and then set $mageRunCode and $mageRunType values depending upon the result of geo-locationing results.

Though this seems to be working but I a have problem - when I manually type in a url say "abcd.com/xyz/pqrs/" then I get redirected to the homepage. Any help on managing multi-websites on same base url would be helpful.